# Why does one of my column shows empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have my table that one of my column shows empty. It has the column of Id, Date, Cust name, Product + Qty, and amount. But only in Product + Qty shows empty even it has data in database.

PHP code

```
 <?php
include('connect.php');
$start = isset($_GET['d1']) ? $_GET['d1'] : '';
$end = isset($_GET['d2']) ? $_GET['d2'] : '';
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit']=='Search')
{
$result = mysql_query(
"SELECT 
   t1.qty, 
   t2.lastname, 
   t2.firstname, 
   t2.date, 
   t3.name,  
   t2.reservation_id, 
   t2.payable FROM prodinventory AS t1
INNER JOIN reservation AS t2
ON t1.confirmation=t2.confirmation
INNER JOIN products AS t3
ON t1.room=t3.id
WHERE str_to_date(t2.date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN
   str_to_date('$start', '%d/%m/%Y') AND
   str_to_date('$end', '%d/%m/%Y')
GROUP BY t2.confirmation") or die(mysql_error());   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo'<tr class="record">';
echo '<td>'.$row['reservation_id'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</td>';
echo '<td><div align="left">';
$rrr=$row['confirmation'];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodinventory where confirmation='$rrr'");
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($results))
            {
                $roomid=$row1['room'];
                $resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where id='$roomid'");
                    while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))
                        {
                        echo $rowa['name'].' x';
                        }
                        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row1['qty'].'<br>';
                        }
                        echo '<td>'.'PHP ' . number_format(floatval($row['payable'])); 
}
?>
```

Comment: It's hard to say form here, but I suppose it's because you are inner joining the tables and there's no data in the intersection of the two tables, try with simple join or right join and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm I have deleted my answer but noone tried so...

I think this `echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row1['qty'].'<br>';` is the row you asked about. And all this looks like a typo. If this is the case:

1. You have no `confirmation` in the SELECT clause (it's used only in JOIN and GROUP BY) and it possible your $rrr to be blank. Echo it to be sure there is a value.
2. Check does your query works and return results. Echo the query string (or take it from the mysql log file) and test it.
3. You have `SELECT *`. Is the field name 'qty' correct in a case-sensivity environment? 'Qty' may be different and the query may work but you don't get the result.

Comment: Should I change my query into Left join?

Comment: Just put `,t1.confirmation` before the first `INNER JOIN` and watch the result

Answer (score 0):

i think that's because you have `inner join` and maybe the intersection tables have no data

try to do `left join`  first if it works

insure that all of tables have data in it